# What is the next number in the sequence below

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

6.000,7.000,.857,8.168,.105,77.790

Which of the following responses completes the series

.001

740.857

9.524

.013

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether these numbers are _exact_ (so e.g. the first one is exactly 6 and the next is exactly 7) or whether these are all 3-decimal-place approximations to possibly-different actual numbers?

Comment: Did you create this puzzle, or did you find it somewhere and need help with it?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> .001

Because:

> The (n+2)-th number is the 3-decimal-place approximation of the ratio of the n-th to the (n+1)-th

Indeed:

> $6/7 \approx 0.857$

> $7/0.857 \approx 8.168$

> $0.857/8.168 \approx 0.105$

> $8.168/0.105 \approx 77.790$

And then:

> $0.105/77.790 \approx 0.001$